# Why does animatedContainer does not work with shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to know the reason why `AnimatedContainer` is not a fluid animation when we try to animate `shape` in flutter ?
Indeed, in the example below, I try to animate **from a rectangle to a circle** using `shape` and `BoxShape`.

UI:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  BoxShape _boxShape;

  _triggerAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _boxShape = BoxShape.circle;
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    _boxShape = BoxShape.rectangle;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _triggerAnimation(),
                  child: Text('Click to Anime')),
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: _boxShape, color: Colors.blue),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tried `ShapeDecoration` instead of `BoxDecoration`?

Comment: and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L308) is why `BoxDecoration` fails with shape

Comment: Thanks. From the doc : "The [shape] cannot be interpolated; animating between two [BoxDecoration]s with different [shape]s will result in a discontinuity in the rendering.  To interpolate between two shapes, consider using [ShapeDecoration] and different [ShapeBorder]s"

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pskink, I found the response.

> **The [shape] cannot be interpolated; animating between two [BoxDecoration]s with different [shape]s will result in a discontinuity in the rendering. To interpolate between two shapes, consider using [ShapeDecoration] and different [ShapeBorder]s**

Source : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L204

Solution with [ShapeDecoration] :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ShapeBorder _shape;

  _triggerAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _shape = CircleBorder();
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _shape = RoundedRectangleBorder();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _triggerAnimation(),
                  child: Text('Click to Anime')),
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: _shape, color: Colors.blue),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the `borderRadius` instead of the shape:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _size = 300;
  double _radius = 0;

  _triggerAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _radius = _size / 2;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => _triggerAnimation(),
                    child: Text('Click to Anime')),
                AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                  width: _size,
                  height: _size,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_radius)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but it was not the way I wanted to deal with the question.